# swift: Move animation

Tags: ios, swift

I have viewController in storyboard. And 4 squares. I want to place my squares on view. At first I want to show two squares. If I press on button I want to my red 2 squares move left and I show next 2 blue squares. Like this animation.

[image]

Do I need to create a `scrollView` or `collectionView` or `something else` to move the squares? What the best way to create this?

Comment: I suggest, if you are making a game, select **Game** and use **Sprite Kit** when you create the project for better performance.

Comment: Im not create a game. In my project this squares is a buttons. And if I press on another button(not squares) I can see second section with blue squares.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Use UiVew.animate and CGAffineTransform

#### Setup

Create a UIView that will contain your squares. **Make sure that UIView has clip to bounds enabled**. Then, add your four squares in, with the blue ones nested inside the UIView, but with their coordinates outside of the container so that they're getting clipped.

[image: View of Storyboard editor]

Then, when you want to move them, you simply translate all of your squares x to the left. By putting this movement inside of a UIView.animate block, iOS will perform the animation for you.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0) {
    self.redTopView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -160, y: 0)
    self.redBottomView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -160, y: 0)
    self.blueTopView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -160, y: 0)
    self.blueBottomView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -160, y: 0)
}
```

Final result: http://g.recordit.co/SToMSZ77wu.gif