# How to define functionality to be executed after a ui transformation

Tags: swift, xcode

I have an element I need to animate and I followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51584169/swift-move-animation/51584507?newreg=858bfe20419942b4bdb8d44b732d7eea) to transform it as follows.

I defined a button that when I click it, the view would move horizontally. However, I need to define certain functions after the transformation (For example, I would need the print statement to be working after the transformation is completed in 5 seconds). But currently, it is printed simultaneously.

How can I define functionality to be done after the transformation.

```
   @IBAction func mybutton(_ sender: Any) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0) {
            
            self.hhview.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -160, y: 0)
            
            print("Voila!")
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a completion handler to execute code after the transformation:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0) {
    self.hhview.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -160, y: 0)
} completion: { _ in
    print("Completed")
}
```

Comment: I've added a similar issue, let me know if you can help there as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65642747/how-to-wait-till-a-uiview-transition-is-over