# How to wait till a UIView transition is over

Tags: swift, xcode

This is related to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65640960/how-to-define-functionality-to-be-executed-after-a-ui-transformation).

I have the following method where it moves a playing card.

```
func moveCard() -> Void{
  UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0) {
    self.hhview.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -160, y: 0)
  } completion: { _ in
    print("Move completed")
  }
}
```

This method is called by different parent methods. But the rest of the parent methods are executed before the completion of the transition. For example, `playerCheck continued` is printed before `Move completed`.

```
func playerCheck() -> Void{
    ......
    moveCard()

    // how to wait till completion of the transition
    print("playerCheck continued")
}
```

How can I set the parent methods to wait till the transformation is completed before executing the rest of the functionality?

Answer (score 2):

Make `moveCard` accept a completion handler, and put all the code "after" `moveCard` in the completion handler:

```
func moveCard(completion: () -> Void) -> Void{
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0) {
        self.hhview.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -160, y: 0)
    } completion: { _ in
        print("Move completed")
        completion()
    }
}
```

```
moveCard {
    print("playerCheck continued")
}
```

If you are going to call another method that has a completion handler, in the completion handler, there might be quite a lot of nesting. You might consider using [PromiseKit](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit/blob/master/Documentation/GettingStarted.md), where you can use `then` to chain these.